# Am I supposed to run `hdfs namenode -format` on all data nodes of a cluster?

Tags: hadoop

I am setting up a Hadoop cluster. From what I understand, the minimum set up for a cluster of at least two workers is 4 machines:

- A name node
- A resource manager
- Data node 1
- Data node 2

I am confused by the `hdfs namenode -format` command, it looks like it's used to format the name node only, but its description (when running an empty `hdfs` command) states *"format the DFS filesystem"*. Does that mean that I should run that command as part of the installation on all data nodes as well, or should it only be run on the name node?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to `format` once. It tells the NameNode to do a format, which is mostly a metadata operation.

You don't necessarily need to do it on the node that the NameNode actually resides. Should be able to do it from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You will also need Node Manager in your cluster on the datanodes for Map and Reduce Operations.

Secondary NameNode is also required for checkpointing.

NameNode format is done only once when you are installing cluster. It can be done from any node in cluster and it should be done only once.